# Proving that the convolution operator on $L^1$ does not have an identity element.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

consider the operator $*$ from $L^1(R^d) \to L^1(R^d)$ with

$$f*g = \int_{R^d}f(x-y)g(y)dy$$

I want to show this operation doesn't have an identity  element, namely, there does not exist an element $I \in L^1(R^d)$ with
$$f*I = f$$
I have argued as follows:

> Assume there exists such an element, hence
> $$\int_{R^d}I(x-y)I(y)dy = I(x)$$
> taking integral from both sides with respect to $x$ and using Fubini-Tonelli's theorem:
> $$\int_{R^d}I(x-y)dx\int_{R^d}I(y)dy = \int_{R^d}I(x)dx$$
> using invariance properties of Lebesgue integral then yields:
> $$\int_{R^d}I(x)dx = 0 \ or \ 1$$
> **case1**$\int_{R^d}I(x)dx = 0$:
> $$\int_{R^d}f(x-y)dx\int_{R^d}I(y)dy = \int_{R^d}f(x)dx$$
> and this yields $\int_{R^d}f(x)dx = 0$ which is a contradiction since $f$ was arbitrary.
> **case2:**$\int_{R^d}I(x)dx = 1$:
> $$\int_f(x-y)I(y)dy = \int_{R^d}f(x)I(y)dy$$
> hence
> $$\int_{R^d}[f(x-y)-f(x)]I(y)dy = 0$$

And I'm stuck here. The best idea I have is to consider some $f$ and evaluate it at some point and get to a contradiction. Any ideas?

Comment: The simplest argument:  the Fourier transform of $L^1$ function tends to $0$ when $\|x\|\to  \infty.$ The answer in the link provided by @P.S.Dester applies more complicated argument.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma implies that for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ we have $$\lim_{\|\xi \|\to \infty }\hat{f}(\xi)=0$$ The Fourier transform of $g(x)=e^{-\|x\|^2}$ does not vanish. We have $$\widehat{f*g}=\hat{f}\,\widehat{g}$$ Assume by contradiction that $f*g=g.$ Then $\hat{f}=1,$ a contradiction.

The argument given in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161025/no-identity-for-convolution-of-lebesgue-integrable-functions) is more complicated in my opinion.

Comment: Actually for relationship $\hat{f*g} = \hat{f}\hat{g}$ you need $\hat{f} \in L^1$ which is a stronger assumption.

Comment: @KhaledAlekasir $f,g\in L^1$ suffices.

Comment: yeah you are right thanks

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $e$ is an identity, then $e * 1_{[0,1]} = 1_{[0,1]}$. Then $1_{[0,1]} (y) = \int 1_{[0,1]}(y-x) e(x) dx$ ae. In particular,
$\int 1_{[0,1]}(y-x) e(x) dx = \int_{y-1}^y e(x)dx= 1_{[0,1]}(y)$ for ae. $y$. Differentiating gives $e(y)=e(y-1)$ ae. and so $e$ is essentially $1$-periodic. Since $e \in L^1$, this gives $e=0$ which is a contradiction.